# Self hosted gitlab + registry displays white blank page only, is that correct?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm running a self hosted Gitlab for my company inside a docker environment and
we want to host our own docker images, so I [read the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html) but I
cannot do `docker login registry.mycompany-domain.tld`, I always get `unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied`
and when I go to `https://registry.mycompany-domain.tld` I only get a blank
page. I don't know if that's correct but I suspect that something is not
working correctly.

Because of firewall reasons, I cannot enable the gitlab image to automatically
fetch Let's encrypt certificates (I need to do it on a different host), so I have the following setup:

- I have a `docker-compose.yml` file in `/opt/gitlab` and I expose these ports:

  - `127.0.0.1:1443:443`
  - `'22:22'`
- in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab` I configure the domain
  `gitlab.mycompany.tld` to proxy `https://localhost:1443`
- the nginx on the main host uses the let's encrypt certificates, the nginx on
  the docker container uses self signed certificates.

This setup works, I'm able to access Gitalb via SSH and Web interface without a problem.

I decided to use a separate domain for the registry:
`registry.mycompany-domain.tld` and then I enabled registry in the obminus
section of the `docker-compose.yml` file. Now it looks like this (the
self-signed certificates are located in `/etc/CA`):

```yaml
--

# generated using example from https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose
# GITLAB_HOME=/opt/gitlab/container

web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:13.11.3-ee.0'
  restart: always
  hostname: gitlab.mycompany.tld
  shm_size: 256m
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.mycompany.tld'
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/certificates/gitlab/gitlab.fullchain.crt'
        nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/certificates/gitlab/gitlab.key'
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        nginx['real_ip_header'] = 'X-Forwarded-For'
        nginx['real_ip_recursive'] = 'on'
        mattermost_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true

        registry_external_url 'https://registry.mycompany.tld'
        registry['enable'] = true
        registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/certificates/gitlab/gitlab.fullchain.crt'
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/certificates/gitlab/gitlab.key'
        gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
        gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "registry.mycompany.tld"

        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
        ...

  ports:
    - '127.0.0.1:1443:443'
    - '22:22'
  volumes:
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    - '/etc/CA:/certificates'
```

and my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/registry` file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name registry.mycompany.tld;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/registry.mycompany.tld-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/registry.mycompany.tld-error.log;

    location /.well-known {
        root /var/certbot/acme-challenges;
    }   

    location / { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }   

}


# see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/registry-ssl
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    server_name registry.mycompany.tld;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/ssl_registry.mycompany.tld-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/ssl_registry.mycompany.tld-error.log;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    ssl on; 

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.mycompany.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.mycompany.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location /{
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass  https://localhost:1443;
        proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/CA/gitlab/gitlab.fullchain.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/CA/gitlab/gitlab.key;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/CA/CA.crt;

        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

If I take a look at `/opt/gitlab/container/logs/registry/current` I can see

```
2021-06-01_16:44:21.01934 time="2021-06-01T16:44:21Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required" correlation_id=xxxx go_version=go1.15.8 root_repo=
2021-06-01_16:44:21.01966 {"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"xxxx","duration_ms":2,"host":"registry.mycompany.tld","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:56368","remote_ip":"xxxx","status":401,"system":"http","time":"2021-06-01T16:44:21Z","ttfb_ms":2,"uri":"/v2/","user_agent":"Docker-Client/20.10.0-dev (linux)","written_bytes":87}
```

I don't really understand what that means. The Gitlab docker container created
automatically a file (`/opt/gitlab/container/data/registry/config.yml`), so I
don't really know what to do.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like he issue may be similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584834/gitlab-docker-registry-with-external-nginx-and-omnibus

Comment: @Shōgun8 thanks for the link, it looks similar, I'll have to read the whole thread.